# How to open html file in go

Tags: html, go

I would like to open a html page in go. My project directory is `home/usr/go/project/`. And my html files are in `/home/usr/go/project/static/`.

I would like to open it as the program starts.

Comment: What do you mean by "open"?

Comment: "Open" could mean open a file with the kernel, an HTTP `GET` request, or render it in a web browser... there are many possible interpretations of "open" here.

Comment: I would like to display html page on screen. Thats what i ment with open.

Comment: David, are you fine with starrting a browser to render that file?

Comment: Run through this guide: https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

Comment: Try to follow this guide before asking questions, you will get (better) answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thats all i needed. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

For actually opening a URL (or file, the browser must ofc reach it) you can use: https://github.com/0x434D53/openinbrowser